# Ввод команд и клавиши курсора больше не работают в rlwrap после обновления

Tags: windows, cygwin, readline

Недавно обновил Cygwin. Теперь программа [rlwrap](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/rlwrap.html) перестала работать.

Воспроизвести можно с cmd.exe (так не используется, только чтобы воспроизвести):

```
~$ rlwrap cmd
```

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.959]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

H:\>dir
exit

_
```

Ни ввод команд, ни клавиши курсора, больше не работают как ожидалось.

Как решить проблему?

---

Следы проблемы есть [в этом архиве](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg163874.html), но ни точных причин, ни воркароунда нету.